# react-native TouchableOpacity's hitSlop to take dynamic width and height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

As per the below code, the click area should be applicable to the whole width and height of the parent view which is dynamic as per the screen width, but it's occurring only for the text area

Code:-

```
        <View style={test1}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick} hitSlop={{ //dynamic data }}>
            <Text>TEXT DATA</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

test1 {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    width: (Dimensions.get('window').width - 30),
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: buttonLightBlue,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: (Dimensions.get('window').height / 3),
    alignSelf: 'center',
    zIndex: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by providing a custom width/height value